# Java Spring MVC ошибка 404

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Только начал изучать spring mvc, так что особо не разбираюсь.
Сначала по видеокурсу решил попробовать написать небольшой код, но в итоге получаю ошибку 404

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-course-mvc</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

appContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.spring.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h2>fdsfsdfsdfsd</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String showFirstView(){
        return "first-view";
    }
}
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Answer (score 0):

Считается ли это решением, но томкэт я решил поставить себе, конечно же, самый последний (10 версию). Если скачать 9 версию - проблема пропадает.

Comment: Проблема может быть в jsp шке и в версии Web.xml. Тоже сталкивался с этим, не хотел jsp читать помойму